# What are the differences bettween null character and '\0'?

Tags: c++

The null character is a control character with the value zero.

As per the documentation(http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/resize/), `std::string::resize()` could extend current string by value-initialized characters (null characters).

Then, could anybody make me clear about the differences bettween null character and '\0'?

When i use `std::string::resize(str)` to extend the `std::string`, it would extend the string with many null characters which **may be** printed to the terminal when executes `std:cout << string << std::endl`.You could check it at http://cpp.sh/4lgvl.

It makes me confused as you say that there's a convention that '\0' means "the end of a string".

Comment: String is pretty much the same as an array of numbers, it just happened that you can add   data in it using literals like "hello" or 'a', but internally it's just an array of numbers. So '\0' is nothing more than a number 0 in a place of a character. There's no trouble having many '\0' in your string just as having many 0 in an array, but there's a convention that '\0' means "the end of a string, so you may not read further", and so when you print a string, it's output is cut to the first occurrence of '\0' == 0

Comment: @Alex Larionov When i use std::string::resize(str) to extend the std::string, it would extend the string with many null characters which could be print to the terminal when executes std:cout << string << std::endl.It makes me confused as you say that there's a convention that '\0' means "the end of a string".

Comment: Seems to be compiler dependent [there](http://cpp.sh/7d2o7) extra space is shown. And [there](https://repl.it/repls/HilariousAshamedCoordinates) is not

Comment: I see.I have checked the playgound you mentioned.I t does not output the extended null characters.But, i  could see the extended null characters indeed.Please check [my playgound](http://cpp.sh/4lgvl) out.

Comment: @Alex Larionov Yea, it's interesting.It's amazing that the output is compiler dependent.I have never noticed it before.I always think '\0' means "the end of a string type of char*".

Answer (score 6):

> Then, could anybody make me clear about the differences bettween null character and '\0'?

There isn't any.  `'\0'` is the null character.  You can't use `'0'` as that is the character `0`, not a character with the value of `0`.  To get a character with the value of `0` you need either

```
char ch = 0;
```

where you initialize with the integer `0`, or you use

```
char ch = '\0';
```

where the `\0` is an octal escape sequence with the value of `0` so you are initializing from the "null char literal" (made this up, not sure if that is actually its technical name).

---

There is also

```
char ch{};
// or
char ch = char();
```

Where you value initialize `ch` and for a `char`, [value initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) means [zero initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization), so `ch` has the value of `0` which is null character value.